# PHP Loop: Every 4 Iterations Starting From the 2nd

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, iteration

I have an array that can have any number of items inside it, and I need to grab the values from them at a certain pattern.

It's quite hard to explain my exact problem, but here is the kind of pattern I need to grab the values:

1. No
2. Yes
3. No
4. No
5. No
6. Yes
7. No
8. No
9. No
10. Yes
11. No
12. No

I have the following `foreach()` loop which is similar to what I need:

```
$count = 1;

foreach($_POST['input_7'] as $val) {        
if ($count % 2 == 0) {
        echo $val;
        echo '<br>';
    }

    $count ++;
}
```

However, this will only pick up on the array items that are 'even', not in the kind of pattern that I need exactly.

Is it possible for me to amend my loop to match that what I need?

Comment: Do you have to use foreach or can you use a for loop?

Comment: Not necessarily, I was just thinking that would be the only way to loop through the array? For loop would be fine too I imagine!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this much simpler with a `for` loop where you set the start to `1` (the second value) and add 4 after each iteration:

```
for ($i = 1; $i < count($_POST['input_7']); $i += 4) {
    echo $_POST['input_7'][$i] . '<br />';
}
```

**Example**:

```
<?php
    $array = array(
        'foo1', 'foo2', 'foo3', 'foo4', 'foo5', 
        'foo6', 'foo7', 'foo8', 'foo9', 'foo10', 
        'foo11', 'foo12', 'foo13', 'foo14', 'foo15'
    );

    for ($i = 1; $i < count($array); $i += 4) {
        echo $array[$i] . '<br />';
    }
?>
```

**Output**:

> foo2
> foo6
> foo10
> foo14

[**DEMO**](http://codepad.org/tDP0SDH5)

Comment: @pealo86 Just be aware of the fact that your array MUST have at least 2 items, or this will bug out. :) If it sometimes won't, surround it by a check for `count()` and have it be `>= 2`.

Comment: Thanks, by this do you mean the $_POST['input_7'] array? If so, this will always have at least 4 items I believe :)

Comment: @pealo86 Yes - as it starts on position 1 (value #2) then it needs minimum 2 values. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$count = 3;

foreach($_POST['input_7'] as $val) {

    if ($count % 4 == 0) {
        echo $val;
        echo '<br>';
    }

    $count ++;
}
```

Comment: You should prefer h2ooooooo's solution if you don't need to keep the foreach loop.